# cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called while tableView.reloadData is called

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm working for the tableview with search bar.
When the search text is changed, I call `tableView.reloadData` to make cells about the search result.
However, even I call `tableView.reloadData`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not called.
So I don't got any cells about the search result.

```
import UIKit

class RestaurantsViewController: UITableViewController,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIBarButtonItem!

var restaurantsData = RestaurantsData()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
    }

    loadRestaurantsData()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}

private func loadRestaurantsData() {
    let 굽네치킨 = Restaurant(name: "굽네치킨", contact: "051-9196-0940", menus: ["고추바사삭":"20000원"])
    let 천궁반점 = Restaurant(name: "천궁반점", contact: "051-2254-0940", menus: ["간짜장":"5000원"])
    restaurantsData.addRestaurant("치킨", restaurant: 굽네치킨)
    restaurantsData.addRestaurant("중식", restaurant: 천궁반점)
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegates

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return 0
    }
    return restaurantsData.restaurantTypes.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return restaurantsData.restaurantTypes[section]
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return filteredRestaurants.count
    }
    return restaurantsData.restaurants[section].count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    let restaurant: Restaurant
    print("\(searchController.active), \(self.searchController.searchBar.text != "")")
    print(searchController.searchBar.text)
    print(searchText)
    print(2)
    if searchController.active && searchText != "" {
        restaurant = filteredRestaurants[indexPath.row]
        print("searched")
    } else {
        restaurant = restaurantsData.restaurants[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
    cell.textLabel?.text = restaurant.name
    return cell
}

// MARK: - UISearchBarDelegates

let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
var searchText: String = ""
var filteredRestaurants = [Restaurant]() {
    didSet { print(filteredRestaurants) }
}

func filterContentForSearchText(searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
    filteredRestaurants = restaurantsData.allRestaurants.filter { restaurant in
        return restaurant.info.containsString(searchText.lowercaseString)
    }
    print("REloaded")

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    print(3)
}

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
    searchText = searchController.searchBar.text!
    print(1)
}

}
```

When I search, the filteredRestaurants array gots info about filtered research, however dose not present on search result table view because cellForRowAtIndexPath is not called.

Comment: There mus be a call for numberOfRowsInSection, which returns zero.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight When I debug the code, I checked that the filterRestaurants array gots some elements while searching. So return filteredRestaurants.count won't return 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning `0` for number of sections when the searchController is active in this part of your code.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != "" {
        return 0
    }
    return restaurantsData.restaurantTypes.count
}
```

Zero sections is an empty table with no cells thats why `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not being called.

Try replacing `return 0` with `return 1` so the table has a section to display your search results.

Answer (score -1):

You have the following code in numberOfSectionsInTableView function:

```
searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text != ""
```

It should be (== instead of !=):

```
searchController.active && searchController.searchBar.text == ""
```